# Data not transfering when using model.addAttribute()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to transfer some default values the user choosed when they click on a dropdown item, but the values are deleted (`null`) when I try to save the passed entity to a repository. When I try and print out the data in HTML, the data is there, it's visible, but when I try to save it to the database, only the data that is in the input field is being saved, even though I'm passing the complete object.

Here is the code:

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/racun/new/{type}/{city}")
    public String createRacunForm(Model model, @PathVariable String type, @PathVariable String city) {
        return racunService.createRacunForm(model, type, city);
    }

@PostMapping("/racun/new")
    public String createRacun(@ModelAttribute("racun") racun racun){
        return racunService.createNewRacun(racun);
    }
```

Service:

```
public String createRacunForm(Model model, String type, String city){
        racun racun = new racun();
        racun.setType(type); //set, has a value chosen by a user
        racun.setCity(city); //set, has a value chosen by a user

        model.addAttribute("racun", racun);
        return "racun_new";
    }

public String createNewRacun(racun racun){
        String type = racun.getType(); //null
        String city = racun.getCity(); //null
        Double price = racun.getPrice(); //read from input by a user
        String desc = racun.getDescription(); //read from input by a user
        
        racunRepository.save(racun); //saved and it prints all attributes but type and city are null
        

        return "redirect:/racun/" + racun.getId();
    }
```

So basically, I create a form using a createRacunForm in controller and take in the parameters the user chose (values are set from chosen dropdown items such as city and type), I then set the type and city using those values and use `model.addAttribute("racun", racun);` to pass the model to a racun_new.html template. In there I tried to print the values so the user sees what they chose and I managed to do that. But when they click on `submit` only the values they entered in the input fields, which are description and price, are being saved and displayed in the `racun/{id]` template... The code comments say where the data exists and where it's null...

Can someone help me understand and explain why this doesn't work as I believe the `model.AddAttribute("racun", racun);` should pass the racun as an object with it's set values?

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: DOn't let your service depend on web classes that is bad idea (the `Model` in this case). The model isn't stored in between requests so unless yo have hidden inputs for `type` and `city` in the form you are submitting nothing will be there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this problem, I used Cookies. I simply set a cookie to remember the value chosen for city and type and the issue was gone.